# Argument labels '(itemsCount:)' do not match any available overloads

Tags: swift

I'm trying to integrate paper on-boarding to my app but this error (Argument labels '(itemsCount:)' do not match any available overloads) is coming through in here:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let onboarding = PaperOnboarding(itemsCount: 3)
```

Can someone help me to fix it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: hi @Bruna, can you share your function declaration?

Comment: A very quick look at the [source code](https://github.com/Ramotion/paper-onboarding/blob/master/Source/PaperOnboarding.swift) reveals that there is no `init` method with parameter `itemsCount`. That's exactly what the error message is telling you . Use code completion to see which `init` methods are available.

Comment: Take a look at the demo project.  It seems the item count is set by a delegate callback much like the way UITableViews work.

Comment: thank you guys! with your help I was able to solve the problem!

Answer (score 1):

`PaperOnboarding` have `delegate` and `dataSource` to specify to how many item there will be.

```
public protocol PaperOnboardingDataSource {

    /**
     Asks the data source to return the number of items.
     - parameter index: An index of item in PaperOnboarding.
     - returns: The number of items in PaperOnboarding.
     */
    func onboardingItemsCount() -> Int

    /**
     Asks the data source for configureation item.
     - parameter index: An index of item in PaperOnboarding.
     - returns: configuration info for item
     */
    func onboardingItem(at index: Int) -> OnboardingItemInfo

    /**
     Asks the color for PageView item
     - parameter index: An index of item in PaperOnboarding.
     - returns: color PageView Item
     */
    func onboardingPageItemColor(at index: Int) -> UIColor
}
```

> Firsty its a hint:

If you forget the assign the delegate and dataSource, you must assign it with your viewController

```
let onboarding = PaperOnboarding()
onboarding.delegate = self
onboarding.dataSource = self
```

Then write a extension for ViewController to say that how many of these prototyping count.

> Add extension for PaperOnboarding

```
extension ViewController: PaperOnboardingDataSource {

        func onboardingItem(at index: Int) -> OnboardingItemInfo {
            return items[index]
            // Items is a OnboardingItemInfo array
        }

        func onboardingItemsCount() -> Int {
            return 3
            // How many item ?
        }
    }
```